# Download server images to android memory card

Tags: android, image, download, upload

I’m doing a android application. I need to fetch the server images and save them in a folder on the android memory card but it is not working. And do not give any error. Can anyone help me?
    And does anyone know how I can browse through the image folder one by one on the server to save the images in a memory card folder.
    thank you

```
Here is my code:

//link to access server images http://IP:8080/teste/imagens/

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new GetImages(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.link), "1.jpg").execute();

    }
}


public class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    private String requestUrl, imagename_;
    private Bitmap bitmap ;
    private FileOutputStream fos;

    protected GetImages(String requestUrl, String _imagename_) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.imagename_ = _imagename_ ;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        if(!ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(imagename_))
        {

            ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, imagename_);
        }
    }
}


public class ImageStorage {
    public static String saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
        String stored = null;
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), "/imagens");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename + ".jpg");
        if (file.exists())
            return stored;
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            stored = "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stored;
    }

    public static File getImage(String imagename) {
        File mediaImage = null;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root);
            if (!myDir.exists())
                return null;
            mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/imagens/" + imagename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mediaImage;
    }

    public static boolean checkifImageExists(String imagename) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/" + imagename + ".jpg");
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        if (path != null)
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        if (b == null || b.equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all avoid using `AsyncTask` for performing network calls. `AsyncTask` has vulnerabilities and can have impact on app performance and stability.

One of the most known cases is when rotation of screen happen and `AsyncTask` is launched. 
Consider that `AsyncTask` is an inner `class` which keeps it's reference to parent `class` if rotation happens `Activity` will be `re-created` but your `AsyncTask` is still holding reference to the first created `Activity` and doesn't allow it to be `garbage collected`.

That leads to scenario known as `zombie`. And if result is returned to `Acitivity` which doesn't exist anymore, that could lead to `leaks` and `crashes`. `AsyncTask` should be used for internal operations like obtaining contacts from phone or similar tasks in background.

So that is why `Retrofit`, `Volley` are introduced in first place but in this scenario `OkHttp` is better choice so:

**Download image using `OkHttp`:**

> `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.0")`

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("put your url of image here")
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
        Log.d("Failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
         InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream(); // convert to inputstream
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream); // get bitmap from inputstream 
    }
});
```